# How to enforce in-order-of-receival processing of async message handlers?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose we have a message handler. Messages might be received from a TCP socket and dispatched to a handler:

```py
async def on_recv(msg):
    await handle(msg)

while True:
    msg = await socket.recv()
    await on_recv(msg)
```

This is problematic because `handle` may take some time or send another message and wait on the socket for a response, and become deadlocked (`on_recv` did not return!). To prevent this, we may make the handler a task so that it does not block us from receiving the next message:

```py
async def on_recv(msg):
    asynico.Task(handle(msg))
```

However, here I believe its true that we lose guarantees about the order of processing (specifically the order in which the tasks start).
Suppose I wanted to make sure that each handler starts is execution in the order of message receival. How might I do that?
My goal here to introduce more deterministic behavior (it's OK where this isn't guaranteed when the handler hits IO boundaries).

In trying to find a solution, it looks like finger puzzle. Everything I try here either leaves messages potentially not starting, involved an scheduler which itself has the same issue of the orginal dispatcher (cedeing order to an `asyncio.Task`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to use a **queue** together with any number of **producers** (that put stuff into the queue) and **consumers** (that take stuff out of the queue).

In this case the obvious choice would be the [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html). Since a queue preserves order, you can have (for example) your main coroutine collect messages and put them in the queue (thus setting the order) and one consumer task asynchronously **consuming** the queue.

Here is a little demo for you:

```py
from asyncio import CancelledError, Queue, create_task, run, sleep
from random import randint

async def receive_message(number: int) -> str:
    seconds = randint(1, 5)
    await sleep(seconds)
    message = f"message {number}"
    print(f"{message} took {seconds} seconds to receive")
    return message

async def handle(message: str) -> None:
    seconds = randint(1, 5)
    await sleep(seconds)
    print(f"processed: {message} (took {seconds} seconds)")

async def consumer(q: Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            next_message = await q.get()
        except CancelledError:
            print("stopping consumer...")
            return
        await handle(next_message)

async def main() -> None:
    q = Queue()
    consumer_task = create_task(consumer(q))
    for i in range(5):
        message = await receive_message(i)
        q.put_nowait(message)
    await consumer_task  # will block forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Sample output: (stopped with `SIGINT` after the last `processed` message)

```
message 0 took 1 seconds to receive
processed: message 0 (took 1 seconds)
message 1 took 2 seconds to receive
message 2 took 1 seconds to receive
processed: message 1 (took 5 seconds)
message 3 took 4 seconds to receive
message 4 took 2 seconds to receive
processed: message 2 (took 3 seconds)
processed: message 3 (took 2 seconds)
processed: message 4 (took 2 seconds)
stopping consumer...
```

As you can easily verify with a few experiments (and prove theoretically), the processing will **always** be in the order the messages are received (`0` to `4`).

Comment: Good point - I guess the trick is to have the worker pull out of the queue, rather than start with the data. So simple.